# customise odoo12 JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, odoo

I want to replace the functionality of the js file. As we have widget many2many in relation_field.js in that there is one function search, that contains code for creating and edit option. I want to change this functionality as per my needs. Following is the main code that I want to change

```
if (create_enabled && !self.nodeOptions.no_create_edit) {
                    var createAndEditAction = function () {
                        // Clear the value in case the user clicks on discard
                        self.$('input').val('');
                        return self._searchCreatePopup("form", false, self._createContext(search_val));
                    };
                    values.push({
                        label: _t("Create and Edit..."),
                        action: createAndEditAction,
                        classname: 'o_m2o_dropdown_option',
                    });
                } else if (values.length === 0) {
                    values.push({
                        label: _t("No results to show..."),
                    });
                }
```

following is my code. I want to add an alert function to create and edit the option of many2many fields. For that, I have use alert function.

```
odoo.define('survey_inherit.create_record',function(require){
"use strict";
console.log("In js file");


var relationalField = require('web.relational_fields');

var FieldMany2One = relationalField.FieldMany2One.include({
        _search: function (search_val) {
            var create_enabled = self.can_create && !self.nodeOptions.no_create;
            if (create_enabled && !self.nodeOptions.no_create_edit) {
                        var createAndEditAction = function () {
                        // Clear the value in case the user clicks on discard
                        self.$('input').val('');
                        **alert(‘Test’);**
                        //return self._searchCreatePopup("form", false, self._createContext(search_val));
                    };
                    this.values.push({
                        label: _t("Create and Edit..."),
                        action: createAndEditAction,
                        classname: 'o_m2o_dropdown_option',
                    });
            }   else if (this.values.length === 0) {
                    this.values.push({
                        label: _t("No results to show..."),
                    });
                }
        }
    });
});
```

can any one please help or any other suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remove assigning your code to `FieldMany2One` variable.

So code will be:

```
odoo.define('survey_inherit.create_record',function(require){
"use strict";
console.log("In js file");


var relationalField = require('web.relational_fields');

relationalField.FieldMany2One.include({
        _search: function (search_val) {
            var create_enabled = self.can_create && !self.nodeOptions.no_create;
            if (create_enabled && !self.nodeOptions.no_create_edit) {
                        var createAndEditAction = function () {
                        // Clear the value in case the user clicks on discard
                        self.$('input').val('');
                        **alert(‘Test’);**
                        //return self._searchCreatePopup("form", false, self._createContext(search_val));
                    };
                    this.values.push({
                        label: _t("Create and Edit..."),
                        action: createAndEditAction,
                        classname: 'o_m2o_dropdown_option',
                    });
            }   else if (this.values.length === 0) {
                    this.values.push({
                        label: _t("No results to show..."),
                    });
                }
        }
    });
});
```